# git: deleting tagged repo content

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a subset git repo which has a lengthy list of
tagged versions corresponding to official releases.  For example
ver-0 to ver-99, where we only have legal approval for a subset of
prior versions (eg: ver-0 to ver-95).

Deleting the latter version tags in the repo is straightforward,
however the content associated with the now deleted tags must also
be deleted from the repo to maintain strict conformance with our
legal restrictions (corporate development environment + lawyers = this_crap).

I can find no way after deletion of the latter tags to prune out
the commits associated with the deleted tags.  Setting the lone
master branch via `git reset --hard [sha-1 of ver-95]` followed
by a `git prune -v --expire=now`, I'd expected to find commits
and blobs uniquely associated with the later version tags to be
found dangling and removed.  However that's not the case.  For
example a `git log [sha-1 of ver-99]` still finds the ver-99
lineage in the repo.

Anyone know of a means to accomplish the above or alternately
explain why the commits/blobs associated with the deleted tags
are not considered dangling?

Comment: I've discovered after the above tag deletion and reset of head to the target end version, performing a clone from the repo the orphaned (+/-) objects don't exist in the new repo.  This does leave the mystery of why the objects weren't purged from the original repo by a prune operation.  Does a method exist to determine for a given object what references exist upon it?  Seems that would help shed light on dependencies in scenarios such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'git prune -v --expire=now' only deletes loose objects older than "now".
You would probably run just

```
git prune -v
```

Comment: Older than "now" is actually what I'm after here.  IIRC prune defaults to expire orphaned objects gt/eq two weeks in age.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the absolute minimum content needed for specific refs, fetch them into a clean repo:

```
git init --template='' some/new/spot
cd !$
git fetch your/old/repo tag1 tag2 tag3 etc 

awk '{print "git",$2,$3,$1}' .git/FETCH_HEAD \
| cat # sh -x
```

and copy any other metadata you want across (`.git/config`, any hooks, etc) manually.